# Eloquent Relationship using DB Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I've got 4 tables.

Clients
Jobs
Rounds
Job_Rounds

I've created the following relationships:

```
Clients > Jobs
Jobs > Rounds
```

Here are my models

**Client**

```
class Client extends Model
{   

    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'last_done'
    ];


    public function Jobs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Job','client_id');
    }
}
```

**Job**

```
class Job extends Model
{
    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'last_done',
        'due_date'
    ];

    public function Round()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Round','round_id');
    }

    public function Client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Client','client_id');
    }
}
```

**Round**

```
class Round extends Model
{
    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'date_scheduled',
        'date_finished'
    ];

    public function Clients()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\RoundClients', 'round_id');
    }

    public function Jobs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Job', 'job_rounds', 'round_id', 'job_id');
    }
}
```

**JobRound**

```
class JobRound extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

On my round view I'm outputting all the jobs not in the round and all the jobs in the round.

I'm doing this by creating a DB::table to perform the check - see my code:

```
public function show($id)
    {   
        $round = Auth::user()->rounds()->FindOrFail($id);

        $not = DB::table('jobs')->whereNotIn('id', function($query) use($round) {
        $query->select('job_id')
          ->from('job_rounds')
          ->where('round_id', $round->id);
        })->get();

        $are = DB::table('job_rounds')
        ->join('jobs', 'job_rounds.job_id', '=', 'jobs.id')
        ->select('job_rounds.*', 'jobs.*' ,'job_rounds.id as DAS')
        ->where('job_rounds.round_id',$round->id)
        ->get();   

        return view('app.round',compact('round','not','are'));
    }
```

The problem I have is in my view, the Client to Job relationship for outputting the client name  won't work as I have created my own DB query, I'm outputting the client information on my view like

**Jobs on the round**

```
@foreach($are as $job)
  {{ $job->client->first_name }}
@endforeach
```

**Jobs not on the round**

```
@foreach($not as $job)
  {{ $job->client->first_name }}
@endforeach
```

I get the error:

> Variable $client not found etc

Comment: have you defined the relationship on the models? can you post the model files for each one

Comment: @Carlos I'm not familiar with doing it in the relationship, i've included the models above.

Comment: why not using basic database table level relationships?

Comment: @Sachith because job can be related to many rounds.

Comment: if you use normal database relationship methods, each job has a client, then each job round has a job.so automatically job round and client relationship is made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your relationships methods starts with uppercase (which btw, you should change to start with lowercase for standard).

The problem is that your methods and the ones you call are not the same, you need to use the same case in both, like this...

```
@foreach($are as $job)
    {{ $job->Client->first_name }}
@endforeach
```

**Update**

Besides the fact of the case, you are not using Eloquent.
You are just using the database query builder directly.
In order to use Eloquent you must use the Model class static methods, like this:

```
Job::whereNoIn('id', .....
```

Instead of this:

```
DB::table('jobs')->whereNotIn('id', ....
```

Comment: Thanks Nestor, I've tried that but I still get the Undefined property: stdClass::$Client

Comment: Ohh, I see, you are not using Eloquent, that is why. You are using the Database Query Builder. If you want to use Eloquent you have to call the Class static methods, like `Job::whereNotIn(.....` instead of `DB::table('jobs')`. If you don't use Eloquent, those relationships are not available.

Comment: I'd love to make to code look cleaner in my controller though :( ha.

Comment: You could use the Repository pattern. https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/

Answer (score 2):

`DB::table` does not return an `App\Job` class. For this reason you cannot use relationship. ( `$job->Client`... )

Try make the queries using Eloquent instead.For more details, follow this offical [Laravel documantation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries).